# Why does my code stop after a while loop?

Tags: java, sockets

I was recently messing around with sockets and transferring data between them, when my program just stopped working after looping through `InputStreamReader#read()`.
I have absolutely no idea why this is happening, and I would appreciate any help possible :)

Here is my code:

```
public class SocketClient
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String host = "localhost";
        int port = 19999;

        String instr = "";
        System.out.println("SocketClient initialized");

        try
        {
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            Socket connection = new Socket(address, port);
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(bos, "US-ASCII");

            String process = "{\"processType\":\"retrieveCoin\",\"uuid\":\"82012e57-6a02-3233-8ee5-63cc5bb52cd1\"}" + (char) 13;

            System.out.println("Querying Data Server: " + process);

            osw.write(process);
            osw.flush();

            System.out.println("Sent data successfully.");

            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("bis");

            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(bis, "US-ASCII");
            System.out.println("isr");

            int c;

            System.out.println("ic");

            while ((c = isr.read()) != 13)
            {
                System.out.println("iwl " + ((char) c));
                instr += ((char) c);
            }

            System.out.println("awl");

            connection.close();
            System.out.println("Recieved data: " + instr);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The console output is fine until the end of the while loop, as the "awl" message does not print, or anything else after that.

The recieving end of the socket (the "server") gets the message okay, and also sends the data out correctly (I'm using some debug messages on the socket server as well).

Please somebody help me, I'm dying here!

Comment: There is a try-catch around everything, and OP says that nothing is printed.

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: What debugger says? It's look like your code stuck in `isr.read()` which is blocking method. `isr` may contain anything except `13`

Comment: No it does not print anything, the problem is that "awl" doesn't even get printed which is when the while loop ends so connection.close doesn't even get called. Here is the console output: `SocketClient initialized
Querying Data Server: {"processType":"retrieveCoin","uuid":"82012e57-6a02-3233-8ee5-63cc5bb52cd1"}

Sent data successfully.
bis
isr
ic
iwl 6
iwl 0
iwl 8
iwl 0`

Comment: Not great - but try changing catch Exception to catch Throwable - in the off chance its an Error being thrown

Comment: I don't want to ask a stupid question, but you've not started an infinite loop have you?  Is it being sent a character code 13?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, the remote side never sends "\r" (or ascii 13) -

```
while ((c = isr.read()) != 13)
{
  System.out.println("iwl " + ((char) c));
  instr += ((char) c);
}
```

And so your loop is blocked waiting for the result from the read. (you should check for -1, which is end of channel). From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html),

> The character read, or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached

And, `-1` is not `13`.

Comment: Thank you very much! The remove side didn't actually send \r which was my problem, thank you very much! (I accidentally commented out the addition of `(char) 13` :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that your "server" process does not send the 13 character.

What you probably wanted to do is to return `stuff + (char) 13`

Comment: I already solved the problem by adding the character, please do not post on old questions people!